# Github Actions - How to use a variable defined in env in the same env section?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to reuse an env variable defined in the same section.

This does not work

```
env:
   HOST: example.com
   URL: $HOST/foo.html
```

It will just yield a verbose "$HOST/foo.html" without host being resolved when used.

I also tried

```
env:
   HOST: example.com
   URL: ${{ env.HOST }}/foo.html
```

this just tells me
*unrecognized named-value: 'env'*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this GitHub Actions forum thread](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-use-env-context/td-p/38951), you can't.

The proposed solution there is to set the base environment variable, at the job level, and then you can use it at the step level.

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Test

    env:
      HOST: example.com

    steps:
    - env:
        URL: ${{ env.HOST }}/foo.html
      run: echo $URL
```

I agree with your intuition - I also expected it to work.